# How do I create a line with 2 consecutive 90 degree angles in a Tikz workflow diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, workflow

I'm having some issues trying to connect my decision node with the second process node. In particular, I'd like to have a horizontal line followed by a vertical line and another horizontal line (- | -).

Further more, I'd like to center my workflows according to the central axis of the workflow. Instead, Latex centers them considering  taking into account the side arrows as well. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot to whoever will answer.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.7cm]
    \node(pro1) [forno]{Trattamenti Termici};
    \node(pro2) [process, below of=pro1]{Lavorazioni Meccaniche};
    \node(dec) [decision, below of=pro2, text width=4cm, yshift=-1.5cm]{Il ciclo prevede ulteriori fasi di TT?};
    \node(stop) [startstop, below of=dec,  yshift=-1.8cm]{M10};
    \node[
    draw,
    densely dotted,
    red,
    inner sep=8pt,
    fit={(pro2) (stop)},
    ] (fit) {};
    \node[above right, inner sep=0pt] at (fit.north west) {UME Nord};
    
    \draw[arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
    \draw[arrow] (pro2) -- (dec);
    \draw[dashed, ->] (dec) -- ++ (3cm,0) node[anchor=east] [above,pos=0.25]{Sì} (pro1);
    \draw [dashed, ->] (dec) -| (pro2);
    \draw[arrow] (dec) --  node[anchor=south] [left,pos=0.25]{No} (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Workflow with incorrect dashed arrow going from (dec) to (pro2)]

Comment: Welcome. // Have a look into the turorials (part I) of the tikz/pgfmanual, which your favorite search engine will find for you.

Answer (score 4):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), that we can test your document example as it is (similar to my MWE below)
- It is not entirely clear where should be feedback loop. I guess as is shown in image below.
- I propose two suggestions. First is "classic" and the second is a bit more "fancy" (as proposed @Qrrbrbirlbel in one of his answers):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth=66mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                ext.paths.ortho,    % -|- and |-| path operations
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
     start chain = A going below,
     base/.style = {draw, fill=#1,
                    text width=32mm, minimum height=7mm,
                    align=center},
startstop/.style = {base=red!30, rounded corners},
  process/.style = {base=orange!30},
       io/.style = {base=blue!30,
                    trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110},
 decision/.style = {base=green!30, diamond, aspect=1.7, inner xsep=-3pt},
      FIT/.style = {draw=red, densely dotted, inner xsep=8mm,
                    fit=#1},
       lb/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=north west]south:#1}},
       ll/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=south east]west:#1}},
      arr/.style = {semithick,-latex},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]
\node   [process]   {Trattamenti Termici};
\node   [process]   {Lavorazioni Meccaniche};
\node   [decision]  {Il ciclo prevede ulteriori fasi di TT?};
\node   [startstop] {M10};
    \end{scope}

\node[FIT={(A-2) (A-4)},
      label={[anchor=south west]north west:UME Nord}] (f1) {};

\draw[arr,dashed]  (A-3.east) -|-[distance=-20mm] (A-2.east) % feedback loop
                    node[pos=0.1, above] {Sì};
\path (A-3) to ["No"] (A-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
or a bit more fancy
\bigskip

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
     start chain = A going below,
     base/.style = {draw, fill=#1,
                    text width=32mm, minimum height=7mm,
                    align=center,
                    on chain=A},
startstop/.style = {base=red!30, rounded corners},
  process/.style = {base=orange!30},
       io/.style = {base=blue!30,
                    trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110},
       if/.style = {base=teal!30, align=left, align=flush center,
                    label={[D=teal]north east:}},
            D/.style = {diamond, draw=#1, fill=#1!60, inner sep=1.6mm,
                        anchor=center},
          lbl/.style = {inner sep=3pt, font=\small, text=black!75},
       lb/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=north west]south:#1}},
       ll/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=south east]west:#1}},
       lr/.style = {label={[lbl, xshift=2mm, anchor=south west]east:#1}},
      FIT/.style = {draw=red, densely dotted,
                    inner xsep=6mm, inner ysep=2mm,
                    fit=#1},
      arr/.style = {semithick,-latex}
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={join=by arr}]
\node   [process]   {Trattamenti Termici};
\node   [process]   {Lavorazioni Meccaniche};
\node   [if,
         lb=Si,
         lr=No]     {Il ciclo prevede ulteriori fasi di TT?};
\node   [startstop] {M10};
    \end{scope}
\node[FIT={(A-2) (A-4)}] (f1) {};
\node[above right] at (f1.north west) {UME Nord};

\draw[arr,densely dashed]  (A-3.east) -|-[distance=10mm] (A-2.east); % feedback loop
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Even more "classic"  ... without od use of the `ext.paths.ortho,` library:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth=66mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, 
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
     start chain = A going below,
     base/.style = {draw, fill=#1,
                    text width=32mm, minimum height=7mm,
                    align=center},
startstop/.style = {base=red!30, rounded corners},
  process/.style = {base=orange!30},
       io/.style = {base=blue!30,
                    trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110},
 decision/.style = {base=green!30, diamond, aspect=1.7, inner xsep=-3pt},
      FIT/.style = {draw=red, densely dotted, inner xsep=8mm,
                    fit=#1},
       lb/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=north west]south:#1}},
       ll/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=south east]west:#1}},
      arr/.style = {semithick,-latex},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]
\node   [process]   {Trattamenti Termici};
\node   [process]   {Lavorazioni Meccaniche};
\node   [decision]  {Il ciclo prevede ulteriori fasi di TT?};
\node   [startstop] {M10};
    \end{scope}

\node[FIT={(A-2) (A-4)},
      label={[anchor=south west]north west:UME Nord}] (f1) {};
\draw[arr,dashed]  (A-3.east) to["Si"] ++ (1,0) |- (A-2); % feedback loop
\path (A-3) to ["No"] (A-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

result is very similar to the first image above.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more question, how do I get fit the red dotted box correctly? The diamond shaped box in the "classic" worklfux stretches out beyond the dotted line

Comment: @europauniversalisenthusiast, increaSE `inner xsep` accordingly. Now corrected. However, beter is make text inside it shorter.

Comment: @europauniversalisenthusiast, BTW, I'm not sure where words "Si" and "No" should be. SO at each image are different positioned ...

Comment: @europauniversalisenthusiast, see addendum to answer.